# for loop in R: How to apply a defined function to loop through rows and columns in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have a dataset named trainset that has 50 variables. For each row, I need to sum up the values under columns called Systolic.Blood.Pressure, Blood.Urea.Nitrogen, Blood.Sodium, Age, heart.rR and COPD values. I already defined a function to sum these up:

```
m.gwtg = function(Systolic.BP, Sodium, COPD){
  if (Systolic.BP>=200){
    pt.sbp = 0
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 190){
    pt.sbp = 2
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 180){
    pt.sbp = 4
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 170){
    pt.sbp = 6
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 160){
    pt.sbp = 8
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 150){
    pt.sbp = 9
  }else if (Systolic.BP>= 140){
  if (Sodium>=139){
    pt.sodium =  0
  }else if (Sodium>= 137){
    pt.sodium =  1
  }else if (Sodium>= 134){
    pt.sodium =  2
  }
  if (Age>=110){
    pt.age = 28
  }else if (Age>= 100){
    pt.age = 25
  }else if (Age>= 90){
    pt.age = 22
  }else if (Age>= 80){
    pt.age = 19
  }else if (Age>= 70){
  if (COPD == 1){
    pt.copd =2
  } else {
    pt.copd = 0
  }
  total = pt.sbp + pt.bun+ pt.sodium +pt.age + pt.hr+ pt.copd
  return(if (total < 79){
    outcome = 0
  } else {
    outcome = 1
  })
}
```

I have problem with coding out the for loop to loop through the trainset and apply the function defined for each row. I tried to code the loop like this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(trainset)) {
  Systolic.BP[i] <- trainset$Systolic.blood.pressure[i]
  Sodium[i]  <- trainset$Blood.sodium[i]
  COPD[i]  <- trainset$COPD[i]
  total[i] <- Systolic.BP[i]+ Sodium[i] +COPD[i]
  
  outcome.gwtg.trainset[i]= m.gwtg(total[i])
  
}
```

I got quite confused on on the code out the for loop. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: `pt` is not defined. (As in `pt.bun = pt + 25`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid loops and similar functions (eg, `*apply()` and `purrr::map()`) whenever possible in R. R is designed to work with *vectors*, and loops are much much slower.

Instead of this loop operation, do the following:

1. Recode each column into its transformed values
2. Add up the transformed values
3. Recode the transformed values into the 0/1 outcome

These operations should be done vector-wise to be efficient (and to avoid the tricky indexing problems you are encountering).

For example:

```r
m.gwtg <- function(data) {
  data <- dplyr::mutate(data, 
    pt.sbp = dplyr::case_when(
      Systolic.BP >= 200 ~ 0,
      Systolic.BP >= 190 ~ 2,
      Systolic.BP >= 180 ~ 4,
      Systolic.BP >= 170 ~ 6,
      Systolic.BP >= 160 ~ 8,
      Systolic.BP >= 150 ~ 9,
      Systolic.BP >= 140 ~ 11,
      Systolic.BP >= 130 ~ 13,
      Systolic.BP >= 120 ~ 15,
      Systolic.BP >= 110 ~ 17,
      Systolic.BP >= 100 ~ 19,
      Systolic.BP >=  90 ~ 21,
      Systolic.BP >=  80 ~ 23,
      Systolic.BP >=  70 ~ 24,
      Systolic.BP >=  60 ~ 26,
      Systolic.BP >=  50 ~ 28, # should Systolic.BP < 50 be NA or 28?
      # else
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ),
    pt.bun = dplyr::case_when(
      BUN >= 150 ~ 28,
      BUN >= 140 ~ 27,
      BUN >= 130 ~ 25,
      BUN >= 120 ~ 23,
      BUN >= 110 ~ 21,
      BUN >= 100 ~ 19,
      BUN >=  90 ~ 17,
      BUN >=  80 ~ 15,
      BUN >=  70 ~ 13,
      BUN >=  60 ~ 11,
      BUN >=  50 ~  9,
      BUN >=  40 ~  8,
      BUN >=  30 ~  6,
      BUN >=  20 ~  4,
      BUN >=  10 ~  2,
      BUN  <  10 ~  0,
      # else
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ),
    pt.sodium = dplyr::case_when(
      Sodium >= 139 ~ 0,
      Sodium >= 137 ~ 1,
      Sodium >= 134 ~ 2,
      Sodium >= 131 ~ 3,
      Sodium  < 131 ~ 4,
      # else
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ),
    pt.age = dplyr::case_when(
      Age >= 110 ~ 28,
      Age >= 100 ~ 25,
      Age >=  90 ~ 22,
      Age >=  80 ~ 19,
      Age <=  70 ~ 17,
      Age >=  60 ~ 14,
      Age >=  50 ~ 11,
      Age <=  40 ~  8,
      Age >=  30 ~  6,
      Age >=  20 ~  3,
      Age  <  20 ~  0,
      # else
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ),
    pt.hr = dplyr::case_when(
      HR >= 105 ~ 8,
      HR >= 100 ~ 6,
      HR >=  95 ~ 5,
      HR >=  90 ~ 4,
      HR >=  85 ~ 3,
      HR >=  80 ~ 1,
      HR  <  80 ~ 0,
      # else
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ),
    pt.copd = dplyr::case_when(
      COPD == 1 ~ 2,
      COPD == 0 ~ 0,
      # else
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
    ),
    total = pt.sbp + pt.bun + pt.sodium + pt.age + pt.hr + pt.copd,
    outcome = dplyr::if_else(total < 79, 0, 1)
  )
  return(data)
}

example_data <- data.frame(
  Systolic.BP = c(170, 160, 200), 
  BUN = c(60, 150, 10), 
  Sodium = c(134, 131, 139), 
  Age = c(40, 80, 20), 
  HR = c(90, 105, 80), 
  COPD = c(1, 0, 0)
)

m.gwtg(example_data)
#>   Systolic.BP BUN Sodium Age  HR COPD pt.sbp pt.bun pt.sodium pt.age pt.hr
#> 1         170  60    134  40  90    1      6     11         2     17     4
#> 2         160 150    131  80 105    0      8     28         3     19     8
#> 3         200  10    139  20  80    0      0      2         0     17     1
#>   pt.copd total outcome
#> 1       2    42       0
#> 2       0    66       0
#> 3       0    20       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, I run this code but there is no result. It just run but there is no outcome shown.

Comment: It's a function like you original function. Apply it to your data. It adds new columns to the dataset for the transformed variables, the total, and the dichotomized outcome.

Comment: Hi, I have checked, but there is no new column added to my dataset

Comment: Hi, to see if the function is working, I created duplicated my trainset, made it trainset2 and tried the codes. Then verified with this : all(trainset == trainset2), the output shows TRUE, which means that there is the code has no effect? Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Did you assign the result of the function to an object? As you can see from my example above, the function definitely adds columns. 

If you aren’t seeing that, post a reproducible example of exactly what code you are running.

Comment: Hi, I managed to spot an error in my code and got the answer. Thanks so much of your comments!

Answer (score 0):

This is a more concise way to calculate the outcome:

```r
library(tidyverse)

calc_score <- function(systolic_bp, bun, sodium) {
  systolic_bp_score <- case_when(
    systolic_bp >= 200 ~ 0,
    systolic_bp >= 190 ~ 2,
    systolic_bp >= 180 ~ 4
  )
  bun_score <- case_when(
    bun >= 150 ~ 28,
    bun >= 140 ~ 27
  )
  sodium_score <- case_when(
    sodium >= 139 ~ 0,
    sodium >= 137 ~ 1
  )
  systolic_bp_score + bun_score + sodium_score
}

# example data
trainset <- tibble(
  systolic_bp = c(180, 195),
  bun = c(145, 180),
  sodium = c(138, 140)
)

trainset %>%
  mutate(
    score = list(systolic_bp, bun, sodium) %>% pmap_dbl(calc_score),
    outcome = as.numeric(score > 97)
  )
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   systolic_bp   bun sodium score outcome
#>         <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1         180   145    138    32       0
#> 2         195   180    140    30       0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I have this error when trying to use mutate: Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `score = list(systolic_bp, bun, sodium, age, hr, copd) %>% ...`.
Caused by error in `is.data.frame()`:
! object 'systolic_bp' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Hi manage to solve the first error by using dplyr:: But I have a second error like this :Error in is.data.frame(.l) : object 'systolic_bp' not found

Comment: You need to change column names accordingly, e.g. replace `systolic_bp` with `Systolic.BP`

Comment: I changed the column names but when I run, it still says object not found

Comment: calc_score <- function(Systolic.blood.pressure, Urea.nitrogen,
                       Blood.sodium, age, heart.rate,
                       COPD) { ............  .....systolic_bp_score + bun_score + sodium_score + age_score + hr_score + copd_score
}                    trainset <- dplyr::mutate(calc_score = list(Systolic.blood.pressure, Urea.nitrogen,
                                        Blood.sodium, age, heart.rate, COPD) %>% pmap_dbl(calc_score),
                           outcome = as.numeric(score >=76)
)
I don't know why this happens.